# How can I implement optimistic locking using mongoengine?

Tags: mongoengine, optimistic-locking

I use [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) to access mongoDB, and I am looking for a simple way to implement an optimistic locking scheme.  Ideally, I would like to have a `version` integer field in the document, and increment it every time the document is modified, just like it is described in the [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/).  Saving a document should fail if the current version of the document object does not match the version of the document in mongodb.

I'm a bit lost with mongoengine.  So far I implemented this.  It works, but I always need to reload objects, which seems really sub-optimal.  Any better idea?

```
class OptimisticLockException(Exception):
    pass

class TodoList(Document):
    name = StringField()
    tasks = ListField(StringField())
    version = IntField()

    def add_task(self, task):
        qs = self.__class__.objects(id = self.id, version= self.version)
        nb_updated = qs.update_one(push__tasks = task, inc__version = 1)
        if nb_updated == 0:
            raise OptimisticLockException("Object was changed.")
        self.reload()  # <= CAN'T I AVOID THIS?

todo_list_1 = TodoList.objects.create(name = "Get rich",
                  tasks = ["Buy bitcoins", "Buy some more"])
todo_list_2 = TodoList.objects.get(name = "Get rich") # get the same

todo_list_1.add_task("Sell everything")
try:
    todo_list_2.add_task("Watch it crash!")
except OptimisticLockException:
    print "It crashed..."

todo_list_1.reload()
print todo_list_1.tasks  # prints [u'Buy bitcoins',u'Buy some more',
                         # u'Sell everything']
```